# Model tournaments between teams

Tags: php, object-oriented

In one of my projects I wrote a little tournament platform, but the way I handle participants is a bit messy and I want to clean this up.

So in my case a Tournament can have participants, but either a User or a Team can signup to become a participant. A participant now holds a user_id or a team_id in the database, and depending on which is filled I determine if a User is linked to the participant or if it's a team.

I rewrote the signup part of my Tournament model to accept both a User or a Team as parameter through am interface and was wondering if this is the correct way to go.

**ICandidate.php**

```
interface ICandidate
{
    public function getName();
    public function hasCorrectGamesSet($tournamentGame);
}
```

**User.php**

```
class User implements ICandidate
{
    private $game;

    public function __construct($game)
    {
        $this->game = $game;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Username';
    }

    public function hasCorrectGamesSet($tournamentGame)
    {
        if($this->game != $tournamentGame){
            throw new Exception('Incorrect name');
        };

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Team.php**

```
class Team implements ICandidate
{
    private $users;

    public function __construct($users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'Teamname';
    }

    public function hasCorrectGamesSet($tournamentGame)
    {
        foreach($this->users as $user){
            $user->hasCorrectGamesSet($tournamentGame);
        }
    }
}
```

**Participant.php**

```
class Participant
{
    private $name;
    private $class;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function setClass($class)
    {
        $this->class = $class;
    }
}
```

**Tournament.php**

```
class Tournament
{
    private $participants;
    private $game;

    public function __construct($game)
    {
        $this->game = $game;
    }

    public function signUp(ICandidate $candidate)
    {
        $candidate->hasCorrectGamesSet($this->game);

        $participant = new Participant();
        $participant->setName($candidate->getName());
        $participant->setClass(get_class($candidate));

        $this->participants[] = $participant;
    }

    public function getParticipants()
    {
        var_dump($this->participants);
    }
}
```

So with this set, I can signup a User or a Team, do a little check and if that passes, add them as a participant to the tournament.

**Logic**

```
$tournament = new Tournament('fifa');

$user1 = new User('fifa');
$user2 = new User('fifa');
$user3 = new User('fifa');
$user4 = new User('fifa');

$team = new Team([$user2, $user3, $user4]);

$tournament->signUp($user1);
$tournament->signUp($team);

$tournament->getParticipants();
```

Is this a correct way to implement this and make use of the interface?

Comment: In general yes. It's [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern)

Comment: The title of the question does not reflect what the code is doing. Put your concerns in the body of the question. The title should be something like `Tournament signup sheet`.

Comment: The code does not seem to be doing anything useful. What Is the purpose of the code?

Comment: given your teams consist of multiple users, why not just have a team of 1 user, then you can do away with the extra complexity

Answer (score 1):

Your code is actually much better than the average. Congrats.

I would change `ICandidate` to `Candidate`. No one needs to know if this is an interface, abstract class, concrete class, etc. Don't break encapsulation.

Also, using types makes your code more readable and less error prone.

I wouldn't also use `getters` and `setters`. For instance:

```php
class Participant
{
    private string $name;
    private string $class;

    public function __construct(string $name, string $class)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->class = $class;
    }

    public function name(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function class(): string
    {
        return $this->class;
    }
}
```

But... do you really need the `Participant` class? From your example, it's not necessary.

In your `Tournament` class, `$participants` is an array of `Candidate`s.

Ah, I would also use namespaces so I would be able to implement autoloading (https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)